# Fixing bad topology

Tags: topology

I'm new to Blender. I modelled a leaf by adding vertexes all along by following the border of the image put as a reference in the 3d view. Now I want to improve the topology. I'm slowly connecting the vertexes horizontally and vertically to form the quads.

Is there a better way to do it? It's very time (and eye) consuming!

[image]Many thanks

Comment: Beauty fill + tris to quads?

Comment: What does it mean? @Lukasz-40sth

Comment: Read the manual.

Comment: Tried them both but they don't work anyway thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could limit the amount of vertices on your boundary edges, it really depends on your final goal actually, if it's for a close-up shot, you can keep it low-poly and add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to smooth it, in that case it will need a bit more vertices than my mesh, in order to sharp some extremities.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! How did you achieve that kind of net so quickly?

Comment: I just began from scratch with a plane, I used your image as background, then draw the borders with some extrudes vertices, join vertices or fill faces with F, add edge loops, etc...

Comment: Many thanks, I think I will start from scratch again! Have a lovely day.

Comment: if you want to keep the original mesh you can automatically delete a part of its vertices, you select all then Select menu > Checker Deselect, then play with the parameters in the Operator box, then dissolve vertices...

Comment: Many thanks, you are really helpful!

Comment: To save even more time you can also grid fill or look into using looptools.