# How to fill ngon with faces?

Tags: modeling

Is there any way to fill such a shape with faces? It would help a lot!

[image]

I'm trying to create something like this, but I have to do it for a lot of leafs. So doing it manually will be a pain.

[image]
Source: https://free3d.com/3d-model/leaf-high-resolution (RobertFreitag)

Of course I could use a more rough shape and use the alpha more, but the alpha is very heavy in big scenes.

[image]

Comment: Hello, it's a bit vague, what kind of faces? a simple grid? what are you trying to achieve at the end?

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the post to make it more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so I'm under pressure and I feel the need to edit.

I gave you the method to print a grid topology on your mesh because that's what you asked. But, unless you have good reason to use this kind of topology, it is actually not very good. You should better use this kind of topology (coming from a [previous question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/176599/fixing-bad-topology) of BSE), which use only quads, can easily be bent and modified with new edge loops, etc. In your case, if you want to keep your current mesh, you can first simplify it with some *Checker Deselect* and *Dissolve Vertices*, then fill with <kbd>F</kbd> and cut some edges with the knife:

[image]

Former answer:

What you can do is first fill your shape with a single face (<kbd>F</kbd>), create a plane, subdivide it to have a grid, delete its faces only, back to *Object* mode put it over the leaf object, <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the leaf, stay in top view, go in *Edit* mode, then *Mesh > Knife Project*. It will print the square grid on the leaf mesh.

[image]

Once filled, you could also give your face several knife cuts, it will create less faces.

[image]

Comment: I was just going to suggest this. Good man. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot you both! Nice solution!

Comment: that's a solution, but it's the worst topology ever. So why even bothering creating subdivision?

Comment: yes I know but that's customer's request  ;)   well actually it might be useful in some cases, I don't know, that's why I asked what was his final purpose

Comment: The reason is to be able to bend the leaf. This topology gives enough control to be able to do that (relative to tri's). Normally I would just model a rough leaf out of a plane, but this particular leaf would have to much alpha due to it's shape. My compuer can handle the vertices when rendering, but not too much alpha.

Comment: once filled, you could also give your face several knife cuts, it will create less faces

Comment: Maybe that's better indeed, and just as fast. Thanks for your help moonboots :) Sorry for my lack of capability haha

Comment: I can see two problems: 1- Generating topology that has nothing to do with the shape of the object, that will prevent proper deformation. Why go for a rectangular grid of faces when the object has none? 2- There are still plenty of ngons, that can yield non planar geometry. Maybe "grid fill" and manual re-position of some vertices will help creating quad only topology.

Comment: again, it really depends on what's the final purpose, at the beginning I just purely answered the question, which was how to make a grid, then I gave an alternative, it can be reworked, it can be kept as it is, depending on tons of things, for example if it's for a low-poly style, with no subsurf, you don't care if you have ngons, plus it was just for demonstration

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, you can do a few freehand adjustments after this tool, like "k"knife, Disolve edges, add vertex, etc, to get a perfect mesh

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer Fabian. The grid fill option gives overlapping faces due to the irregular shape. But the smooth brush to ease the topology is a great addition!