# Rounded mouth when using subdivision surface

Tags: modeling

I can't make my character smiling when I use subdivision surface.
[image: Without subdivision]

[image]

[image]

Comment: U didn't understand me. I don't want to make lips smoother or sharper. I want to make my character smile. As u see in the first picture (low poly) character is smiling but in the second picture character's mouth is neutral not smiling. This situation is every time although I make smile bigger.

Comment: You need understand the Subsurf how to work. Try add more loop cut

Comment: It worked. Thank you <3

Comment: Your problem is a fundamental topology issue.  The area around your mouth is an ngon, and subdivision will be unpredictable. somewhat related -- https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/179705/how-to-fill-ngon-with-faces

Comment: You need to make the lips sharper so that the character can smile using subsurf... Etiher by creasing or using support loops. But it would help also if you fixed the overall topology of the object, and avoided all of those n-gons (faces with more than 4 vertices, that are only going to give you headaches down the line...